# How do i sent a event from a webpage to a client application

Tags: python, mysql, wordpress

I have a webpage(Wordpress) updating some tabel information in the MySQL database. And i have a client application on aother pc runing a standalone Pythonscript accessing the same MySQL server for getting and setting data. 
How do i implment a trigger from my webside that can trigger an event in my python code to see if the data in database are updated, without polling the mysql db ?
Is there som simple Message Queue I can implement easy or how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use sockets, another solution is to convert python script into webapp with api (e.g. use Flask) and when your wordpress page sends get/post http request to python script and tirgger python script to go checking db. The second one is easier to implement from my point of view. Sockets are more difficult for me.

Comment: Ok how can i from a webserver send post request to a specific client? I do not know the ipadress of the client connected ?

Comment: @EsbenJensen unfortunately without knowing ip address of pc you can't create communication between your Wordpress website and the PC script, so they can communicate with each other only through database. Thogh you can do all vice versa, create api in Wordpress website and send http requets from pc, let Wordpress to create some file and change flag in the file  when the webiste changed DB.

Comment: I decide to use WPMQTT protocol to signaling my client, it works.

Comment: @EsbenJensen never hear of this Wordpress plugin WP-MQTT, thanks for sharing!